# How to remove quoted deleted files in git repository

Tags: git, quotes, rm

when I use git status, it shows:

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    "project/Resources/font-365\345\211\257\346\234\254.png"
```

how to use git rm to remove it?
I have tried:

```
git rm project/Resources/font-365\\345\\211\\257\\346\\234\\254.png
git rm \"project/Resources/font-365\\345\\211\\257\\346\\234\\254.png\"
```

they don't work

Answer (score 0):

I got a method how to solve it, using:
    git commit -am "done"
this way, the git delete all the files that are not staged and do the commit

but it is not a elegant way I think, does anyone know how to delete it using "git rm"?